# iOS13: NumberFormatter no hay groupingSeparator al formatear números con 4 cifras usando cualquier locale con idioma español

Tags: ios, swift, numberformat

Acabo de actualizar el proyecto en el que trabajo a iOS 13 y me he dado cuenta de que el formatter que estaba usando para dar formato a los precios no funciona correctamente.

El símibolo para agrupar los miles: `groupingSeparator`, ha desaparecido para los números de 4 cifras: de 1000 a 9999, cuando uso el locale `es_ES`.

Adjunto un pequeño snippet código muy sencillo para ilustrar el problema.
`NumberFormatter` funciona perfectamente cuando usa el locale `en_US` o cuando trabaja con números mayores de 9999, pero al usar el locale `es_ES` si intento formatear 1000, no hay separador de miles, en vez de 1.000 obtengo 1000.

```swift
let enFormatter = NumberFormatter()
enFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
enFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
enFormatter.string(from: 1000)
enFormatter.string(from: 9999)
enFormatter.string(from: 10000)
enFormatter.string(from: 100000)

let esFormatter = NumberFormatter()
esFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "es_ES")
esFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
esFormatter.string(from: 1000)
esFormatter.string(from: 9999)
esFormatter.string(from: 10000)
esFormatter.string(from: 100000)
```

Pégalo simplemente en un playground para ver la salida.

[image: Different outputs for en_US and es_ES NumberFormatter]

Qué me estoy perdiendo?

De momento ya he informado a Apple: `FB7416623`
https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/7416623 (no sé si el link funciona)

Trataré de mantener esto actualizado, pero agradecería si alguien más tiene más información.

Answer (score 0):

Según la RAE (Real Academia de la lengua) [aquí](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=PxrAnmVfND6FK0uGdT), y la fundéu (Fundación del Español Urgente) [aquí](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/miles-6498/), sólo se debería añadir el símbolo de los miles para números de más de 4 cifras.

Además, establecen que el símbolo ya no debería ser el punto "**.**", sino el espacio en blanco. Por ejemplo:

```
1000  -> 1000
15000 -> 15 000
```